# post method does not get payload object

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Order {

    private String orderCode;

    // And many more ... getters and setter

}
```

And the following REST resource:

```
@Path("/customers/{customercode}/orders")
public class OrderResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(@PathParam("customercode") String customerCode, Order order) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now some client sends an `Order` object as JSON to this URL. The `customerCode` parameter gets set to the expected value, but the `order` parameter is `null`, although here is a valid JSON body in the request. (I can see it in the `ContainerRequestContext` object.)

Jersey's log says nothing about any problems (even in DEBUG mode).

Any ideas? TIA! (I am using Jersey 2 with Jackson)

Comment: Hmmm... so you read it from the `ContainerRequestContext`? Was this just to debug or was this already part of your application (to read the request from the context)?

Comment: @peeskillet Okay. I see. I read the stream (as a part of my application) and now it is empty => `null` as `Order`

Comment: Here is a trick. Cast the `ContainerRequestContext` to `(ContainerRequest)`. Use `ContainerRequest.bufferEntity()`, then `ContainerRequest.readEntity(Order.class)`

Comment: Is there a ways to get the raw content (like with `ContainerRequestContext.getEntityStream()`) without knowing any class-types or media-types?

Comment: `readEntity(InputStream.class)` maybe?? or `String.class` if you are always expecting textual data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in your filter you are reading the `InputStream` from the `ContainerRequestContext`. So now the stream is empty. That means no data left for when the method param deserialization is done.

One way around this is to buffer the entity before reading it. We can do that by casting the `ContainerRequestContext` to [`ContainerRequest`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.html), which will give us many more methods to interact with the context.

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    ContainerRequest containerRequest = (ContainerRequest)requestContext;
    containerRequest.bufferEntity();
    Order order = containerRequest.readEntity(Order.classs);
    // or
    InputStream in = containerRequest.readEntity(InputStream.class);
}
```

The call to `bufferEntity()` will do exactly what the method name implies. Also if you are familiar with working with the client API, the `readEntity` should look familiar. It works pretty much the same way as `Response.readEntity(...)`. It looks for a `MessageBodyReader` for the inbound Content-Type. The [`MessageBodyReader` for `InputStream`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/InputStreamProvider.java) doesn't do anything special, but just return the orginal stream. So if you need it, there it is.